# Shortest path between 2 points with an obstruction

Tags: geometry

From this image:

[image: shortest path]

What is the shortest path between the two endpoints, given $d$ is the distance from the left endpoint to the boundary of the circle, and $r$ is the radius of the circle?

I am tied between the main diagonal and along the line, but some intermediate might work too.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227469/what-would-be-the-shortest-path-between-2-points-when-there-are-objects-obstruct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

The upper figure below depicts your arrangement with a piece of red thread fixed to the left side of the horizontal rod. We pull the thread upward as shown. The thread will take the shortest path when tight.

[image]

So the solution is to construct the two tangent lines to the circle from the left and from the right.